# jquery не видит переменную в window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, javascript-events, type-error

Я пытаюсь создать переменную (объект), затем отредактировать ее после загрузки DOM. В данном случае в переменной pageQuery находятся селекторы, которые становятся объектами jquery в переменной page.

```
var pageQuery = {
    someSelector: '.select'
}
var page = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var key in pageQuery) {
        page[key] = $(pageQuery[key]);
    }
});
```

Но когда я пытаюсь использовать переменную page в другом js файле, также в событии document ready, то получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: page.someSelector is undefined
```

Насколько я понимаю, это происходит из-за того, что оба эти события выполняются асинхронно и независимо друг от друга. Но вообще не понимаю, как тогда решить данную проблему.

UPD1: Также второй скрипт запускается по window.load и window.resize, и там все нормально работает.

UPD2: На счет window.load (точнее $(window).on('load')) я был не прав. Как раз в document.ready все работает прекрасно, а вот с window.load и возникает ошибка. Вообще, window.load почему-то происходит до document.ready, причем это никак не зависит от моего скрипта, это происходит любом документе. Возможно я просто чего-то не понимаю, но мне казалось, что window.load должен в любом случае происходить позже, после полной загрузки страницы.

Comment: jQuery отлично видит переменную в document.ready. Просто ваш второй скрипт скорее всего запустился до этого прекрасного события и в page ещё ничего нет

Comment: Изначально я так и понял. Но как тогда запустить второй скрипт после?

Comment: Запустить его в document.ready

Comment: Так я его там и запустил.

Answer (score 0):

Размести скрипт с обращением к `page.someSelector` внутри подписки на `ready`, причём расположенной в коде после того фрагмента, который приведён в вопросе.